# JavaScript: Regex to remove string from one tag to another

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
<style>body p{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;} div{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;}span{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;} h1{max-width:100% !important; height: auto!important;}h2{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;}h3{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;}h4{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;}h5{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;} img{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;}iframe{max-width:100% !important;height: auto!important;}
</style><span style="background-color: rgb(68, 68, 255);">#followforfollow #likeforlike yo!</span>
<h2></h2>
<h3></h3>
<h2></h2>
<h1></h1><u></u>
```

in this I want to remove everything inside the style tags. Can anyone please tell me the optimal solution.The expected output is:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
<span style="background-color: rgb(68, 68, 255);">#followforfollow #likeforlike yo!</span>
<h2></h2>
<h3></h3>
<h2></h2>
<h1></h1><u></u>
```

Comment: please add what have you tried so far to remove the mentioned string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the regex you are looking for. Short and simple.

```js
var str = `<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
<style>body p{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;} div{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;}span{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;} h1{max-width:100% !important; height: auto!important;}h2{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;}h3{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;}h4{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;}h5{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;} img{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;}iframe{max-width:100% !important;height: auto!important;}
</style><span style="background-color: rgb(68, 68, 255);">#followforfollow #likeforlike yo!</span>
<h2></h2>
<h3></h3>
<h2></h2>
<h1></h1><u></u>`;

//replace everything between <span></span>
str = str.replace(/<style>(.|\r?\n)*<\/style\>/,'');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for regex since there are DOM methods available to deal with it.

Create a dummy `div` element and use `querySelector` to remove the child `style` element.

```
var div = document.createElement( "div" );
div.innerHTML = str; //your input string
div.removeChild( div.querySelector( "style" ) );
console.log( div.innerHTML );
```

**Demo**

```js
var str = `<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
<style>body p{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;} div{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;}span{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;} h1{max-width:100% !important; height: auto!important;}h2{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;}h3{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;}h4{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;}h5{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;} img{max-width: 100% !important;height: auto!important;}iframe{max-width:100% !important;height: auto!important;}
</style><span style="background-color: rgb(68, 68, 255);">#followforfollow #likeforlike yo!</span>
<h2></h2>
<h3></h3>
<h2></h2>
<h1></h1><u></u>`;

var div = document.createElement( "div" );
div.innerHTML = str;
div.removeChild( div.querySelector( "style" ) );
console.log( div.innerHTML );
```

Comment: No need to lengthen the code when you can achieve that using `regex`

Comment: Yes it is as compared to one.

Comment: And also the OP asks for regex solution

Comment: I meant it is not lengthy enough to become unreadable and is anyways more readable than a regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery then you don't need to use regex.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('style').remove();
});
```